# Does mongodb community server support two phase commit?

Tags: mongodb, two-phase-commit

Does mongodb community server support single phase commit or two phase commit.

Comment: Check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/currentOp/#_S_currentOp.twoPhaseCommitCoordinator, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851659/two-phase-commit-in-mongodb, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716582/two-phase-commit-with-mongodb

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ are available in community server if that is your question.